# Auth0 with Angular 2: form does not show when navigating back

Tags: angular, auth0

In my login component I use the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.lock.magiclink({
        container:"login",
        callbackURL:"http://localhost:3000",
        responseType:"token"});
}
```

which inserts the Auth0 form inside the following div in the HTML template:

`<div id="login">SHOULD NOT DISPLAY THIS MESSAGE</div>`

But when I navigate away from the page containing the component, then back, the Auth0 form no longer appears.

Instead, **SHOULD NOT DISPLAY THIS MESSAGE** is displayed.

When I reload the page, the Auth0 form reappears.

> Why does the Auth0 form only show at first load?
>
> How can I force the Auth0 form to display when navigating back to the login page?

Comment: If you search Google for `ngOnInit not firing` you'll see a couple of hits so that may be a good starting point; If you already done that, try reproducing the problem with the minimal amount of code needed and then include the full sample in the question or use something like [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. NgOnInit is firing (checked with console), but for some reason the form does not display when navigating back to the form page. Tried to reproduce in plunkr, but could not (it worked in the plunk). Difference between my local dev and the plunk is I am using angular2-webpack-starter for dev.

Comment: I would try to break down what you have to the minimal; doing this will either identify the problem by itself or leave you with a very condensed sample app that reproduces the issue and that you can share in order for others to better help you out. The previous Google hits I mentioned do reference that there are lot of smaller details can lead to similar issues, like including scripts in a different order so unless someone already experienced that issue is very difficult to try to help without a sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: thank you, will try that and keep you updated...